# Angular refresh validateFn on element in other function

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I have such element in my component.html:

```
<app-form-datetime-block
        [settings]="settings.endDateInput"
        [disabled]="disabledEnd"
        [(ngModel)]="model.endDate"
        (changed)="modelChanged($event)"
        [minDate]="model.minDate"
        [maxDate]="model.maxDate"
        [validateFn]="validateEnd"
        [showEmptyFields]="showEmptyFields"></app-form-datetime-block>
```

This is how my validateFn declared in component.ts:

```
validateEnd = (term: moment.Moment): boolean => {
if (this.model.startDate) {
  this.checkNearShortTerm(moment(this.model.startDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true).toDate(), term.toDate());
  if (!this.checkLongTermDates(moment(this.model.startDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true).toDate(), term.toDate())) {
    return false;
  }
  const m = moment(this.model.startDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true);
  return m < term;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Now it called just when the date in datetime input has been changed. And "term" is the value from this input.
How can I call it from some other function to change my validation manually?

I tried to do this in this way:

```
isLongTermChanged($event) {
  this.changed.emit($event);
  if (this.model.startDate && this.model.endDate) {
     this.checkLongTermDates(moment(this.model.startDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true).toDate(), 
                             moment(this.model.endDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true).toDate());
     validateEnd = (term: moment.Moment): boolean => {
        return this.someCheckFucntion(this.model.startDate, this.model.endDate);
     }
  }
}
```

But validation of my date input doesn't change when someCheckFunction returns true or false. And in this case "term" is undefined because isLongTermChanged function called from other event, not from date input.

Answer (score 0):

I've built an example for you. It includes communication via a subject. It has a subject where 1 method will trigger this subject and the other will observe and do the calculation (validate).

My example explained: If you hit the trigger button it will trigger the validate field; and the function inside will randomly disable or enable the input field. So in your case the randomization is your validation logic

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ouncx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

The main idea is to turn your validate function into an observable. So the method will go inside these lines:

```js
subject$ = new BehaviorSubject("");

validateEnd$ = this.subject$.pipe(
    map(res => {
      // your validation logic here
      /* return (term: moment.Moment): boolean => {
         if (this.model.startDate) { ....
      */
    })
  );
  
trigger() {
  this.subject$.next("trigger!");
}
```

My `validate$` field in the example returns a boolean in the stackblitz but that's just for simplicity. You can return your function there like in the above code block.

Also make sure you subscribe to this subject via the `async` pipe in the html like I did in my example

```html
<app-form-datetime-block
        [validateFn]="validateEnd$ | async"
```